# new lambda literal syntax for activerecord callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, lambda

I wonder if this is possible?

```
after_create -> { some_method_from_model }, if: :should_be_executed?
```

Syntax is ok, but the Proc will be called/executed or just created?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you want to call a method on the model the best approach would be passing the model as an argument for your lambda, and then using it to invoke the desired method, like so:

```
after_create -> (model) { model.some_method }, if: :execution_condition_satisfied?
```

This is because the value of `self` inside the lambda isn't the model but a Proc object and, without an explicit receiver, Ruby tries to invoke the method in `self`.

In your example, Ruby will try to find `some_model_method` in the Proc object. So no, your example would not work, but that's **not related to the new lambda literal syntax**.

I hope it helps ;)

Comment: So the Proc got executed? rails fire the call method?

Comment: I don't know for which version of Rails this answer was intended, but at leas in Rails 4.2 `self` inside the lambda is the instance, so you don't need to pass it as an argument.

Comment: `after_create -> () { some_method }` is enough

Answer (score 0):

This seems overly complicated to me.  I would just put the if test inside the method which is being called.

```
after_create :some_method

def some_method
  if condition_satisfied
    #do the stuff
  end
end
```